# Chain multiple JOIN or GroupJOIN on different datasets in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

The final response I am expecting should look like this:

```
[
    {
        "ID": 4,
        "Floor": "BackOffice Floor",
        "OverallDescription": "Pretty Pretty Good",
        "Permit": "Admin",
        "TabOne": [
            {
                "Color": "Blue",
                "status": "ReadWrite"
            },
            {
                "Color": "Purple",
                "status": "ReadOnly"
            },
        ],
        "TabTwo": [
            {
                "Color": "Black",
                "status": "Offline"
            },
            {
                "Color": "Green",
                "status": "Online"
            },
            {
                "Color": "White",
                "status": "Blinking"
            },          
        ],      
        
    }
]
```

**I modelled a `class` for that like this:**

```
public class AllSheets
{
    // from parent calss
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Floor { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string OverallDescription { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Permit { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    
    // from children classes
    public IEnumerable<SheetChildOne> TabOne { get; set; } = Enumerable.Empty<SheetOne>();
    public IEnumerable<SheetChildTwo> TabTwo { get; set; } = Enumerable.Empty<SheetTwo>();
}
```

And here are the those three `classes`, one is the `parent` and the other two are `children`. Their `JOIN` is on the `ID` field.

```
public class SheetMain
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Floor { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string OverallDescription { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Permit { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

public class SheetChildOne
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Floor { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Color { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Status { get; set;} = string.Empty;
}

public class SheetChildTwo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Floor { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Color { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Status { get; set;} = string.Empty;
}
```

Notice that I **don't want to repeat** some of the fields that are common in both child and parent so for example `ID` and `Floor`.

I was able to start writing it myself but I had two things I need help with:
**1:** How can I have more than one group-join in my query so I can include SheetChildTwo too.
**2:** How can I tell it NOT TO include some of the repeated fields that are both in parrent and child such as ID and Floor in this example.

Here is what I tried:

```
var result =
            sheetMain.GroupJoin
            (sheetChildOne,
                work1 => work1.ID,
                work2 => work2.ID,
                (t1, t2) => new AllSheets
                {
                    ID = t1.ID,
                    Floor = t1.Floor,
                    OverallDescription = t1.OverallDescription,
                    Permit = t1.Permit,                        
                    TabOne = t2.Select
                    (b => new SheetChildOne
                        {
                            Color = b.Color,
                            Status = b.Status,
                        }
                    )
                }
            );
```

Comment: I am interested in helping you with this one. What doesn't make sense to me is in your query you are using sheetChildOne, sheetMain as collections, but in the defention you have above is classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following query. Used query syntax as it is more readable here:

```cs
var query = 
    from s in sheetMain
    join co in sheetChildOne on new { s.ID, s.Floor } equals { co.ID, co.Floor } into coG
    join ct in sheetChildTwo on new { s.ID, s.Floor } equals { ct.ID, ct.Floor } into ctG
    select new AllSheets
    {
        ID = s.ID,
        Floor = s.Floor,
        OverallDescription = s.OverallDescription,
        Permit = s.Permit,
        TabOne = coG.ToList(),
        TabTwo = ctG.ToList()
    };
```

Comment: Pretty much 99% of the time query syntax is a complicated and unreadable mess, but I have to admit, here it's nice and clean. Just you forgot to add a step that the TabOne and TabTwo need to be converted to a type that will hide the unnecessary properties.

Comment: ah! I see how the two joins can be both using the main sheet and not result set of previous join .. cool cool .

Comment: Actually C# compiler will make all needed transparent projections. It is benefits of Query Syntax.

Answer (score 1):

This feels like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).
My quick experiments with the subject.

In both cases console displays:

```json
[
  {
    "ID": 4,
    "Floor": "BackOffice Floor",
    "OverallDescription": "Pretty Pretty Good",
    "Permit": "Admin",
    "TabOne": [
      {
        "Color": "Blue",
        "Status": "ReadWrite"
      },
      {
        "Color": "Purple",
        "Status": "ReadOnly"
      }
    ],
    "TabTwo": [
      {
        "Color": "Black",
        "Status": "Offline"
      },
      {
        "Color": "Green",
        "Status": "Online"
      },
      {
        "Color": "White",
        "Status": "Blinking"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

1. Anonymous objects

```cs
using System.Text.Json;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sheetMain = new List<SheetMain>();
        var tabOne = new List<SheetChildOne>();
        var tabTwo = new List<SheetChildTwo>();

        sheetMain.Add(new()
        {
            ID = 4,
            Floor = "BackOffice Floor",
            OverallDescription = "Pretty Pretty Good",
            Permit = "Admin",
        });

        tabOne.Add(new() { ID = 4, Floor = "BackOffice Floor", Color = "Blue", Status = "ReadWrite", });
        tabOne.Add(new() { ID = 4, Floor = "BackOffice Floor", Color = "Purple", Status = "ReadOnly", });

        tabTwo.Add(new() { ID = 4, Floor = "BackOffice Floor", Color = "Black", Status = "Offline", });
        tabTwo.Add(new() { ID = 4, Floor = "BackOffice Floor", Color = "Green", Status = "Online", });
        tabTwo.Add(new() { ID = 4, Floor = "BackOffice Floor", Color = "White", Status = "Blinking", });

        var result = sheetMain.Select(sm => new {
            sm.ID,
            sm.Floor,
            sm.OverallDescription,
            sm.Permit,
            TabOne = tabOne
                .Where(t1 => t1.ID == sm.ID)
                .Select(t1 => new { t1.Color, t1.Status }),
            TabTwo = tabTwo
                .Where(t2 => t2.ID == sm.ID)
                .Select(t2 => new { t2.Color, t2.Status }),
        });


        var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(result, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });

        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}
```

2. Dedicated Classes

```cs
using System.Text.Json;

public class SheetChildDTO
{
    required public string Color { get; set; }
    required public string Status { get; set; }
}

public class AllSheetsDTO
{
    // from parent calss
    required public int ID { get; set; }
    required public string Floor { get; set; }
    required public string OverallDescription { get; set; }
    required public string Permit { get; set; }

    // from children classes
    required public IEnumerable<SheetChildDTO> TabOne { get; set; }
    required public IEnumerable<SheetChildDTO> TabTwo { get; set; }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sheetMain = new List<SheetMain>();
        var tabOne = new List<SheetChildOne>();
        var tabTwo = new List<SheetChildTwo>();

        sheetMain.Add(new()
        {
            ID = 4,
            Floor = "BackOffice Floor",
            OverallDescription = "Pretty Pretty Good",
            Permit = "Admin",
        });

        tabOne.Add(new() { ID = 4, Floor = "BackOffice Floor", Color = "Blue", Status = "ReadWrite", });
        tabOne.Add(new() { ID = 4, Floor = "BackOffice Floor", Color = "Purple", Status = "ReadOnly", });

        tabTwo.Add(new() { ID = 4, Floor = "BackOffice Floor", Color = "Black", Status = "Offline", });
        tabTwo.Add(new() { ID = 4, Floor = "BackOffice Floor", Color = "Green", Status = "Online", });
        tabTwo.Add(new() { ID = 4, Floor = "BackOffice Floor", Color = "White", Status = "Blinking", });


        var result = sheetMain.Select(sm => new AllSheetsDTO() {
            ID = sm.ID,
            Floor = sm.Floor,
            OverallDescription = sm.OverallDescription,
            Permit = sm.Permit,
            TabOne = tabOne
                .Where(t1 => t1.ID == sm.ID && t1.Floor == sm.Floor)
                .Select(t1 => new SheetChildDTO() { Color = t1.Color, Status = t1.Status }),
            TabTwo = tabTwo
                .Where(t2 => t2.ID == sm.ID && t2.Floor == sm.Floor)
                .Select(t2 => new SheetChildDTO() { Color = t2.Color, Status = t2.Status }),
        });


        var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(result, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });

        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}
```